# Options controlling PDF Output

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I came across a line in a LaTeX file reading `\pdfoptionsminorversion=6`.  This changed the minor version of PDF, which I confirmed by looking at the generated PDF.  Now, this option doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, so I'm curious.  What other options and/or environments exist to control PDF output?

Comment: The `pdftex` manual mentions some obsolete commands, such as `\pdfoptionpdfminorversion` -- Did you mean that command?

Answer (score 28):

The option is now called `\pdfminorversion` (since pdfTeX 1.30.0 2005-08-01).
It is documented in the pdfTeX [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/pdftex/manual/pdftex-a.pdf):

> ▶ `\pdfminorversion` (integer)   This primitive sets the PDF version
>   of the generated file and the latest allowed PDF version of included
>   PDFs. E.g., `\pdfminorversion=3` tells pdfTeX to set the PDF version
>   to 1.3 and allows only included PDF files with versions numbers up to
>   1.3. The default for `\pdfminorversion` is 5, producing files with PDF version 1.5. If specified, this primitive must appear before any data
>   is to be written to the generated pdf file, so you should put it at
>   the very start of your files. The command has been introduced in
>   pdfTeX 1.30.0 as a shortened synonym of `\pdfoptionpdfminorversion`
>   command, which is now obsolete.
>
> Distributions alter the default value here; for example, TeX Live 2010
>   sets `\pdfminorversion=5` when its formats are built, so object
>   compression can be enabled (described below).

It's not entirely correct, because the default value for the current pdfTeX 1.40.15 (without
further configuration) is 4. Table 2 shows this correct value.

### Some support by packages:

- Package [`pdf14`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdf14) sets the PDF version to 1.4 (i.e. before object stream compression).
- Package `hyperref` has an option `pdfversion` for setting the PDF version.

### Other TeX engines/DVI drivers:

- LuaTeX: `\pdfminorversion` as in pdfTeX.

  In Lua it is more complicate, because `tex.pdfminorversion` does not throw
  an error message, if its setting has no effect, because the version is already
  written. The very beginning of an PDF file, the PDF header, already starts with the version number (e.g. `%PDF-1.5`). Example for setting the version to 1.4:

  ```
  \directlua{
    if tex.pdfminorversion \string~= 4 then
      if (status.pdf_gone and status.pdf_gone > 0)
      or (status.pdf_ptr and status.pdf_ptr > 0) then
        tex.error("PDF version cannot be changed anymore")
      else
        tex.pdfminorversion = 4
      end
    end
  }
  ```

  For luatex version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016):

  ```
  \directlua{
  if pdf.getminorversion() \string~= 7 then
    if (status.pdf_gone and status.pdf_gone > 0)
    or (status.pdf_ptr and status.pdf_ptr > 0) then
      tex.error("PDF version cannot be changed anymore")
    else
      pdf.setminorversion(7)
    end
  end
  }
  ```
- dvipdfm(x)

  - Command line option:

    ```
    -V number     Set PDF minor version [4]
    ```

    Example:

    ```bash
    dvipdfmx -V 4 test.dvi
    ```
  - `\special{pdf:minorversion 3}` to `\special{pdf:minorversion 7}` (see [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202300/options-controlling-pdf-output/202301?noredirect=1#comment698816_202301) of AndreKR). If several specials are given, then the latest special on the first page wins and specials after the first page are ignored. Also unsupported values are silently ignored.
- XeTeX

  - The version can be set by the command line option `-V` (see `dvipdfmx`) for the output driver (`xdvipdfmx`). The option can be passed to the output driver by XeTeX option `-output-driver` on the command line:

    ```bash
    xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -V4" test.tex
    ```
  - `\special{pdf:minorversion 3}` to `\special{pdf:minorversion 7}` (see [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202300/options-controlling-pdf-output/202301?noredirect=1#comment698816_202301) of AndreKR). If several specials are given, then the latest special on the first page wins and specials after the first page are ignored. Also unsupported values are silently ignored.
- Ghostscript provides shorthand commands: `ps2pdf12`, `ps2pdf13`, `ps2pdf14` can be used to generate PDF files with versions 1.2, 1.3, or 1.4. `ps2pdf` currently sets 1.4, from the shell script `ps2pdf`:

  ```bash
  # Currently, we produce PDF 1.4 by default, but this is not guaranteed
  # not to change in the future.
  version=14
  ```

  The full ghostscript option for setting the PDF version, e.g. 1.4:

  ```
  -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4
  ```

Comment: Is there an updated place where we could find all those commands documented?

Comment: @Manuel `texdoc pdftex`?

Comment: @Manuel I did check and it definitely includes the new version. I wouldn't like to guarantee it doesn't mention the old ones.

Comment: For Xe(La)TeX it can also be set from the document using `\special{pdf:minorversion 4}`. This is the method that the `bxpdfver` package uses.

Comment: @AndreKR Many thanks, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Using luatex version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) the suggestion does not work for me. I want to change the version to 1.7.

Comment: @Hotschke Thanks for the update with the new functions of LuaTeX 0.95.

Comment: It doesn't seem to give an error when setting it to version 1.3 and importing 1.4 PDFs. Is that normal? The included PDFs to have transparencies which I thought only worked in >=1.4 and the transparencies still work in the produced PDF which actually is shown to be version 1.3 by `exiftool`. Seems like the produced PDF is kinda invalid but still works anyway?

Comment: But PNGs which do use transparency now have black backgrounds.

Comment: @mxmlnkn If you are using features of PDF 1.4, then do *not* downgrade the version to PDF 1.3. PDF viewers can ignore higher features, if the PDF version is wrong.