# Set PDF version with LuaTeX and pdfx

Tags: luatex, pdfx

Consider the following example using the package `pdfx` version 1.5.8, setting the PDF version as suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202301/99345 for LuaTeX 0.95:

```
\directlua{
if pdf.getminorversion() \string~= 7 then
  if (status.pdf_gone and status.pdf_gone > 0)
  or (status.pdf_ptr and status.pdf_ptr > 0) then
    tex.error("PDF version cannot be changed anymore")
  else
    pdf.setminorversion(7)
  end
end
}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a-2b]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
Content
\end{document}
```

When building the PDF output with LuaTeX version 1.0.4, the following error occurs:

```
! error:  (pdf backend): minorversion cannot be changed after data is written to the PDF file
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Omitting the package `pdfx` produces a PDF document with the correct version number `1.7` set. How can the desired PDF version number be set in combination with LuaTeX and pdfx?

Comment: As pdfx sets the minor version too, you can't set it before loading the package. pdfx has an option (pdf17) to set it, but due to a bug (hyperref options are not passed correctly) it has no effect.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Is that bug known to the package developers? I could not find a bug tracker for `pdfx`.

Comment: I didn't reported it, I didn't had the time yet (and also wanted to assemble a number of suggestion first). Write Ross a mail. It is mostly `\expandafter`'s missing, e.g. like this `\expandafter\hypersetup\expandafter{\pdfx@pdfAE@opts@xetex}`

Comment: I reported the issue to him.

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: Also, the package says: `\pdfminorversion=4 %  assumed for PDF/A ;  options may change this for  PDF/X`. I changed that and apparently hyperref is loaded with the correct version, but I still get a PDF with version 1.4...

Comment: Well, when loading `pdfx` with one of the pdfa-options, then `hyperref`'s own option `pdfa` is loaded which sets the pdf version back to 1.4:
`\kvsetkeys{Hyp}{pdfversion=1.4}`

Comment: @Martin Do you consider this a bug of the `hyperref` package? Then it should be reported there. Obviously, reporting the problem to the `pdfx` maintainers had no effect yet.

Comment: Looking into `pdfx.sty` I see that none of the available compliance choices use minor version 7. The highest is minor version 6. However, there is a class option `pdf17` for over-riding that, which allows minor version 7. But I don't know if this will help. Has nothing to do with the Lua code. Sadly, the package is named `pdfx` even though most users seem to want PDF/A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in `hyperref` versions prior to `v6.86a` with the `pdfa` option, which set the PDF always to version 1.4. The latest version of hyperref (>6.86a) fixes that problem.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is solved with current versions. Rephrase your answer or post a new one and I will accept it as a solution to the question.