# How to set the pdf major version in latex?

Tags: tex-core

For example, in `lualatex` I can do:

```
\typeout{pdfmajorversion=2}
\typeout{pdfminorversion=0}
```

But in latex I found out that I can use `\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=0`, but `\pdfoptionpdfmajorversion=2` does not work for me. Is it really the major version of pdf in latex?

Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: Do you mean pdflatex? That engine does not support changing the major version, it is hardcoded to 1.

Comment: Nice overview of related options for different engines: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202301/36296

Comment: @Marcel Krüger Yes,i mean pdflatex.

Comment: 'We' (LaTeX team) are aware of this, and have started discussions about addressing PDF v2 in various places (its not just pdfTeX). But that will be non-trivial: we will need to test out changes.

Comment: For anyone else (like me) wondering what's new in PDF 2.0 and not wanting to pay 198 CHF to buy the spec, there's some info from [slides 11 to 32 here](https://www.pdfa.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/PDF20Keynote.pdf#page=10). IMO for most people there will be no need to change from the versions that have been stable for over a [decade](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=History_of_the_Portable_Document_Format_(PDF)&oldid=873991566); and in any case simply changing the version number without related compliance doesn't make sense, and without viewers it may be hard to test anyway.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR the interesting (and important) parts in 2.0 for us are the changes in Tagged PDF and Associated Files. Accessibility gets important, see e.g. a current discussion here https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5409.

Answer (score 2):

pdfTeX (now) offers `\pdfmajorversion` as well as `\pdfminorversion` but a hard-coded major version. (This first appeared in the TL'20 release of pdfTeX.) As such, with a recent release you can mark a PDF as being essentially any version - the reality of course is that this does not mean that the PDF will be *valid* for PDF 2.0.

Comment: What is the latest status regarding `\pdfmajorversion`? What is the latest stable version of PDF that we can specify and use with pdfTeX?